# Get a list of entities by list of guids

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a partial list of entities for a list of entities by their guids.

could be accomplished by:

```
List<Entity> GetEntitiesByGuids (List<Entity> entities, List<Guids> guids)
{
  List<Entities> retVal = new List<Entities>();
     foreach(var guid in guids) 
     {
      var Entity = Entities.Find(e=>e.Guid ==guid)
      retVal.Add(Entity);
     }
return retVal;
}
```

Is there any nice way to do it without `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance-wise the best way of filtering list against another list is to use hashed collections because with hash we have fast lookup (that has complexity of almost O(1))

First let's measure time, required by using normal `List<Guid>` of hashes :

```
public static List<Entity> GetEntitiesByGuids(List<Entity> entities, List<Guid> guids)
{
    return entities?.Where(e => guids.Contains(e.Guid)).ToList();
}
```

And `Main()` method in both cases is :

```
var entities = new List<Entity>();
var guids = new List<Guid>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) entities.Add(new Entity() {Guid = guids[i]});

var guidsToFilter = guids.Skip(12000).Take(40000).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Started to filter list");

var s = new Stopwatch(); s.Start();

var result = GetEntitiesByGuids(entities, guidsToFilter);

s.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds+"ms");
```

Result: 19823ms

Now let's introduce `HashSet<T>` collection :

```
public static List<Entity> GetEntitiesByGuids(List<Entity> entities, List<Guid> guids)
{
   var hashedGuids = new HashSet<Guid>(guids);        
   return entities?.Where(e => hashedGuids.Contains(e.Guid)).ToList();
}
```

Result: 11ms

Comment: Thanks for this technique! Is there any performance-oriented overview about framework collections you can suggest?

Comment: Well, you can read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx) and [this](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-collection-for-string-lookups) articles if you're interested. It's just about first two that showed on google search so there is plenty of good stuff about the matter.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a nice way of doing it WITH foreach:

```
IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntitiesByGuids (EntityList entities, List<Guids> guids)
{
     foreach(var guid in guids) 
     {
         yield return Entities.Find(e=>e.Guid ==guid);
     }
}
```

Comment: What is especially 'nice' about it?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Entity> GetEntitiesByGuids (List<Entity> entities, List<Guids> guids)
{
    List<Entities> retVal = entities.Where(e => guids.Contains(e.Guid)).ToList();
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: This will return the results in a different order than the question

Comment: pay attention to `entities.Where(e => ...` typo and `EntityList entities` instead of `List<Entity> entities`

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Levkovsky, fixed.